# Not able to insert record into a custom object

Tags: api, java

I am having some difficulty inserting a row into a custom object. I am writing a java application that will insert rows into a custom salesforce object. There is no exception that is thrown, so I don't understand what I am missing. I can retrieve data, but the write does nothing.

here is a code snippet from my program

```
    Licence__c license = new Licence__c();
    license.setActive__c(true);
...
license.setSubscriptionID__c("a0bM000000BbK5v");
license.setContact__c("003M000000bVb6J");
SaveResult[] result = conn.create(new SObject[] { license });
```

result returns with one entry, but the value of 
result[0].getId(); 
returns null

Any clues as to what I might be missing. I don't think it is a permissions issue, because I am able to create license object through saleforce using the same credentials.

I would really appreciate some clues as to what I might be doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: are you checking if the create was successful? E.g. result[0].isSuccess(). In case it's not, then getId() will be null and getErrors() will get you the error.

Comment: thank for the hit Guy. That helped me take care of my issue.